# Can't read data from tf.data.Dataset.from_generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I hope to use tf.data.Dataset.from_generator to help me generate the input data flow.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(sample_generator,
                                         output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32), 
                                         output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([size_image, size_image, 3]),tf.TensorShape([size_image,size_image,3]), tf.TensorShape([size_gt, size_gt])))
```

sample_generator function could generate three numpy arrays with the proposed shape.

There is no problem with the part mentioned above.
However, tf.data.Dataset.from_generator could only generate the data flow, I need to feed the generated data to network.

The code is as follows:

```
dataset = dataset.map(transform_fn, num_parallel_calls=self.config['prefetch_threads']) # transform_fn just returns the input

dataset = dataset.prefetch(self.config['prefetch_capacity'])
dataset = dataset.repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(self.config['batch_size'])
```

and the iterator is

```
self.iterator = self.dataset_tf.make_one_shot_iterator()

self.iterator.get_next()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved.
from_generator are changed to generate meta data, e.g. , the name/path of files you need.

Then, use a
    tf.Py_func
to preprocess the data in an ordinary/numpy way.
I just want to say:"tf.Pyfunc is so convenient!"
Thanks!